# I created a parser and AST using PLY but the AST is not working

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc, lex

I'm trying to write an AST for a parser which parses a specific grammar I defined and I'm using Python/PLY for this. Here is the grammar:

- start : function | function option
- function : forward | right | loop | color | pen
- option : start | empty
- forward : F numbers
- right : R numbers
- loop : L numbers [ start ]
- color : COLOR colors
- colors : BLACK | BLUE | GREEN | RED
- pen : PEN numbers

I wrote a lexer and parser but the parser needed an AST because of the loop rule. So, I'm trying to write a proper AST but there are some problems in the code. I think I'm missing something.

I tried to define a root Node class but I'm not sure if it's true. Here is:

```
class Node:
     def _init_(self,type,children=None,leaf=None):
          self.type = type
          if children:
               self.children = children
          else:
               self.children = [ ]
          self.leaf = leaf
```

Then, I defined some classes for each nodes:

```
class Start(Node):
    def  _init_(self,func,opt):
        self.func=func
        self.opt=opt
class Forward(Node):
    def _init_(self,forw,num1):
        self.forw=forw
        self.num1=num1
        def forw(num1):
            pattern.forward(num1)
class Right(Node):
    def _init_(self,rght,num2):
        self.rght=rght
        self.num2=num2
        def right_(num2):
            pattern.right(num2)
class Loop(Node):
    def _init_(self, num3, stmt):
        self.num3 = num3
        self.stmt = stmt
class Color(Node):
    def _init_(self,col,rgb):
        self.col=col
        self.rgb=rgb
class Pen(Node):
    def _init_(self,size,num4):
        self.size=size
        self.num4=num4
    def pensize(num4):
        if num4 == 1:
           pattern.pensize(1)
        elif num4 == 2:
           pattern.pensize(3)
        elif num4 == 3:
           pattern.pensize(5)
```

And here is how I used the classes in rules:

```
def p_start(p):
    '''start : function 
             | function option'''
    if len(p)==2:
        p[0]=p[1]
    elif len(p)==3:
        p[0]= Start(p[1],p[2])

def p_function(p):
    '''
    function : forward
             | right
             | loop
             | color
             | pen
    '''
    p[0]=p[1] 

def p_empty(p):
    'empty :'
    pass
 
 
def p_option(p):
    '''option : start
              | empty '''
    p[0]=p[1]

def p_forward(p):
    'forward : FORW NUMBER' 
    p[0]= Forward(p[1],p[2])
    
 
def p_right(p):
    'right : RIGHT NUMBER'
    
    p[0]= Right(p[1],p[2])

def p_loop(p):
    'loop : LOOP NUMBER LSQB start RSQB '
    i=1
    while i<=p[2]:
        p[0]= Loop(p[2],p[4])
        i+=1


def p_color(p):
    'color : COLOR colors'
    p[0]=Color(p[1],p[2])
def p_colors(p):
    '''colors : BLACK 
              | BLUE
               | GREEN
              | RED '''
    if p[1] == 'S':
        p[0]=pattern.color("black")
    elif p[1] == 'M':
        p[0]=pattern.color("blue")
    elif p[1] == 'Y':
        p[0]=pattern.color("green")
    elif p[1] == 'K':
        p[0]=pattern.color("red")

def p_pen(p):
    'pen : PEN NUMBER'
    p[0]=Pen(p[1],p[2])
```

When I run the program, I get this error:

[image: error]

And turtle runs but stops to respond. I can't find where I'm doing wrong and I'm pretty confused about the AST. Why AST does not work?

Comment: You spelled `__init__` incorrectly. Dunder methods start and end with two underscores, not one.

Comment: Of course, that's not your only problem. But it's the immediate problem.

Comment: @rici yeah, I saw that and fixed actually. What about other problems?

Comment: @rici the error is gone but AST still doesn't work properly.